# Oracle: Use a cursor to check whether a record in one table exists in another

Tags: oracle, syntax, cursor

As a POC for my non-technical team I need to come up with several ways to do the same thing which is to check whether a record in one table exists in another in order to see which is the most efficient. I've come up with two other ways that I am positive will be more efficient than a cursor, but I still need to show the time it takes to do this in a cursor. I can't figure out the syntax however.

I have two tables:

Table 1 has two fields I need and that I am fetching into the variables in the cursor:

Field = ID
Field = Account number

Table 2 has one field I need:

Field = Account Number (No ID available)

I need the ID from table 1 and the count of transactions where the account number from table 1 is not in table 2. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're asking about the syntax of Oracle cursors? - What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing so far :(. I can't get a handle on it I keep staring at the following trying to figure out how to change the following code:loop
   fetch PAN_VAL into IFN,CardNo;
   
   insert into holding2 (input_feed_name,card_no)
     select input_feed_name,card_no from table1 where
     card_no not in (select cardno from table2);
 
     END LOOP;

Comment: It would help if you could provide enough information for us to see and try out what you're trying to do - a test case, including create table scripts, sample input data and the code you've attempted so far, would be perfect here. Please update your original post with this information.

Comment: However, I would question the need to check if a row exists in another table though - I've seen this type of thing used to decide whether to do further dml quite unnecessarily. Why are you doing this check in the first place? It may be that you don't even need to do it.

Comment: _"I still need to show the time it takes to do this in a cursor"_ So, you are _deliberately_ looking for a _slow_ way to perform an [anti-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29) ? _"I need the ID from table 1 and the count of transactions where the account number from table 1 is not in table 2."_ That part is not quite clear -- we definitively need an example...

Answer (score 1):

Given that sample data:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM T1;
 ID 
 -- 
  1 
  2 
  3 

SQL> SELECT * FROM T2;
 ID 
 -- 
  2 
  3 
  4
```

The proper way to perform an [anti-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29) T1 ▷ T2 is by writing:

```
SQL> SELECT ID FROM T1 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM T2);
 ID 
 -- 
  1
```

Now, if you want to do it using cursor to show how slow that can be, you might want to use two nested loops like in the following example:

```
DECLARE
 CURSOR c1 IS (SELECT ID FROM T1);
 r1 c1%ROWTYPE;
 CURSOR c2 IS (SELECT ID FROM T2);
 r2 c2%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
 FOR r1 IN c1
 LOOP
  FOR r2 IN c2
  LOOP
   IF (r1.ID = r2.ID)
   THEN
    -- continue to the next iteration of the outer loop
    -- as we have a match
    GOTO continue;
   END IF;
  END LOOP;
  -- we can only reach that point if there was no match
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(r1.ID));
  <<continue>>
  NULL;
 END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I follow you, but a simple cursor might look like this:

```
DECLARE 
v_id NUMBER;  
v_acct NUMBER;  
BEGIN  
FOR r1 IN ( SELECT ID, ACCT_NBR  
            FROM table1 T1  
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table2  
where ID = T1.ID )  
) LOOP  
v_id := r1.id;  
v_acct := r1.acct_nbr;  
-- do something  
END LOOP;  
end;
```

Comment: Hi!  I'm sorry to be so late to respond!  The performance was terrible as expected.  Thank you for the help!!